# V-Align 1 cell with Tabularray

Tags: tabularray

Using `tabularray`, I want the *xxx* in the first cell to be vertically aligned in the middle.

How do I v-align one cell?

I tried typing, in the table settings,

```
cell{1}{1} = {valign=m}
```

I also tried inside the cell, with no success:

```
\SetCell{m}
```

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}[t]{
cell{1}{1} = {valign=m}, % This doesn't work.
hline{1,8} = 2pt,
hline{2} = 1pt,
hline{3-7} = 0.5pt,
vline{1,6} = 2pt,
vline{2} = 1pt,
vline{3,4,5} = 0.5pt}
\SetCell{m}\textbf{xxx} & {line1\\line2} & {line1\\line2} & {line1\\line2} & {line1\\line2}\\
\textbf{row1} & x & x & x & x\\
\textbf{row2} & x & x & x & x \\
\textbf{row3} & x & x & x & x\\
\textbf{row4} & x & x & x & x\\
\textbf{row5} & x & x & x & x\\
\textbf{row6} & x & x & x & x
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the alignment of the first cell, but the alignment of the other cells in this row. Change the alignment of the taller cells to `m` and you'll get the desired result.

Instead of using `cell{1}{2-5} = {valign=m}` it might be easier to just do this for the whole first row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}[t]{
  row{1} = {valign=m},
  hline{1,8} = 2pt,
  hline{2} = 1pt,
  hline{3-7} = 0.5pt,
  vline{1,6} = 2pt,
  vline{2} = 1pt,
  vline{3,4,5} = 0.5pt,
  column{1} = {font=\bfseries}
}
xxx & {line1\\line2} & {line1\\line2} & {line1\\line2} & {line1\\line2}\\
row1 & x & x & x & x\\
row2 & x & x & x & x \\
row3 & x & x & x & x\\
row4 & x & x & x & x\\
row5 & x & x & x & x\\
row6 & x & x & x & x
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assumed the whole table would be middle-aligned by default?

Comment: @VincentKrebs t is the default for the vertical alignment

Comment: What should I type to get m by default on the table?

Comment: `cells = {valign=m}`

Comment: Any idea why `cell{1}{1} = {valign=m}` does not work?

Comment: It works, but you won't see the result, because the other top aligned cells are taller. They will top align with the single line first cell. It does not matter if the first cell is mid, bottom or top aligned, it still only has a single line.

Comment: @everyone For all tables to be middle-aligned by default, use the command:

`\SetTblrInner{cells={valign=m}}`